# Как правильно обновить haskell-stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

В мануале сказано, что после установки стека из репозитория (ОС - ubuntu 18.04) необходимо выполнить следующую комманду:

```
stack upgrade --binary
```

После завершения обновления stack сообщил, что его новая версия находится в *~/.local/bin*. Теперь у меня две версии: одна - по вышеуказанному пути, другая - в */usr/bin*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет необходимости в данном случае ставить stack из репозитория. Можно сразу ставить актуальную версию, загрузив инсталлятор, как описано здесь: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/

Теперь же, после обновления, можно смело удалить пакет:

```
sudo apt remove haskell-stack
```

Не забудьте добавить путь `~/.local/bin` в `PATH`.

Comment: Спасибо Евгений!